# How to choose an item in form:select component?

Tags: forms, jsp, spring-mvc

I got this `form:select` in my JSP file:

```
            <form:select id="locale" path="locale">
                <form:option value='${preferredLanguage}' />                    
                <form:options itemValue="key" itemLabel="value" items="${locales}" />
            </form:select>
```

After the page is being rendered, the selected item is added as a first item and as a another item.

I tried to solve it using:

```
defaultValue='${preferredLanguage}'
```

Either:

```
defaultLabel='${preferredLanguage}'
```

And it didn't succeed, any other ideas how to solve it ?

Comment: why the single quotes? You can just do it normally...  value="${preferredLanguage}"

Comment: Does it matter ?

Comment: hmmm i guess not. \*backs slowly away\*

Answer (score 0):

I used to fixed it using `if-else`, solution:

```
<form:select id="locale" path="locale">                 
    <c:forEach items="${locales}" var="loc">
        <c:choose>                          
        <c:when test="${loc.key == currentLocale}">
            <option class="bdi" itemValue="key" value="${loc.key}" selected><bdi><div>${loc.value}</div></bdi></option>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <option class="bdi" itemValue="key" value="${loc.key}"><bdi><div>${loc.value}</div></bdi></option>
        </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>                                     
    </c:forEach>
</form:select>
```